# which algorithm did this transform used, image calibration?

Tags: image, algorithm, calibration

[image: Source Image]

[image: Target Point Set]

There is a source image which has a set of points and  target point set, then we can use an algorithm to transform the source image to target image. So which algorithm can me use to do this?

[image: Target Image]